# Route не рендерит компонент при ручном вводе url адреса

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Делаю небольшое SPA с несколькими страницами, навигацию выполняю средствами react-router. При клике на `<Link />` страницы Route рендерит нужный компонент правильно, но при ручном вводе url - ftp сервер кидает ошибку.
Роутинг происходит в `<App>` компоненте:

```js
import React, {useState}  from 'react';
import clasess from './App.module.css';
import Header from './components/header/header'
import { SlideMenu } from "../src/components/slideMenu/SlideMenu"
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import theme from "./styles/theme"
import { Route } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes';

function App() {

 return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className={clasess.App}>
        <Header volume = {volume} toggleVolume = {toggleVolume} />
        <SlideMenu/>

        {
          routes.map((route, index) => (
            <Route path={route.path} component={route.component} key={index} />
          ))
        }

      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте настройки сервера - скорее всего это он 404 выдает и до реакта не доходит.

Например, если у вас приложение находится на урле /app/, то при /app/some-page/ на nginx'e такой код будет работать верно

```
 location ~ ^/app(/.*)?$ {
```

а такой падать

```
location ~ ^/app/$ {
```